# Is there an in-browser code editor with build-in preview?

Tags: html, text-editor

I found some code editor plugins eg:http://codemirror.net/ and http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/#nav=about , but not sure whether they can create a preview for the codes. Is there any in-browser code editor plugin that have come along together with the preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, in almost all browsers. Its called `Code Inspector` using which we can edit HTML and CSS and we can preview it in the browser window itself.

Lookup for `code inspector <browser-name>` on Google.

Comment: Hi, Rahul Desai, may be I have caused some confuse for you, what I'm trying to say here is a plugin that can be embedded into the html page (eg: jsfiddle -code and preview), but not using browser window code inspector. Any idea?

Comment: @user2991183 What is wrong with embedding jsFiddle? If not jsFiddle, you might want to check out CodePen and jsBin. Here is how to [embed CodePen](http://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens/) and [embed jsBin](http://jsbin.com/help/how-can-i-embed-jsbin).

Comment: @user2991183 By the way, Code Mirror already does what you need. Checkout [this demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/preview.html).

Comment: thanks for your answering, because I'm trying to create CMS website and the interface is something like jsfiddle, where experience user can insert the code and get preview directly, then store the code in database. Is it possible to get the code inserted by user to store in database if using jsfiddle?

Comment: thanks for your link demo... that's what I'm looking for... =)

Comment: @user2991183 Not sure if it can be done with jsFiddle because it uses an iFrame. With CodeMirror, it might work because its not using an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inspect element in Google Chrome

In Google Chrome browser, **rightclick->Inspect Element**

Answer (score 0):

Both Google Chrome and Later versions of IE have this feature.
You can access this by pressing the *F12* key whilst the browser is open on the page.

Alternatively, in chrome, *right click - Inspect Element*